# Replacing text in stringbuffer without hardcoding indexes

Tags: string, replace, stringbuffer

I have a Stringbuffer object which contains data "**Detail is:**"

Based on the result of a HashMap(Map), I populate the details below this line with help of looping through the map and fetching data.

Now I want to replace the text "Detail is:" with "Details are:" if more than one record is fetched.

*Is their any way to achieve this?*

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can:

1. Get the string out of the stringbuffer.
2. Reset the stringbuffer and write the new beginning.
3. Write all after the replaced Prefix back to the buffer.

Instead, you could also do this:

1. Omit the Prefix in the first place
2. Do a simple string-concatenation at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can even do like this if Map size is greater than 1

```
StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
if(map.size>1){
    sb.append("Details are:")
}else{
    sb.append("Details is:");
}
```